# RenderTexture.Create failed in Unity. please help me

Tags: unity, game-design, sprites

RenderTexture.Create failed: width & height must be larger than 0
UnityEngine.RenderTexture:Create()
Prime31.SpriteLightKit:updateTexture(Boolean) (at Assets/SpriteLightKit/SpriteLightKit-master/Assets/SpriteLightKit/SpriteLightKit.cs:177)
Prime31.SpriteLightKit:OnEnable() (at Assets/SpriteLightKit/SpriteLightKit-master/Assets/SpriteLightKit/SpriteLightKit.cs:75)

Comment: I've downvote this question because it does not describe the problem in context. We have only the error message but not the snippet of code that generates the error or any background information about what feature you're trying to implement or what changes you made that led to the error. The question also does not demonstrate any debugging steps taken so far, like verifying the size of the texture before trying to create it. If you can edit the question to improve it in these areas, I'll happily reverse my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a texture with 0 size (apparently). You shoud pass with and height of the texture. If you don't know, try to use a square creation (256x256 for example).

From Unity [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Create.html):

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public RenderTexture rt;
    void Start() {
        rt = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        rt.Create();
    }
}
```